# How can I set the zoom of the map so that my routes can be entirely seen? (here.com api)

Tags: javascript, maps, gis, here-api

I'm making an application using here.com api, and I need to auto adjust the zoom of the map so that when loading, the routes displayed are entirely visible?
Basically, I want all polylines to be within the boundary of the starting frame. As is, if my routes are too long, parts of them are hidden out of the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example of that functionality on developer.here.com in the [JavaScript API Explorer](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/servicesRouting/map-with-route-from-a-to-b)

```
function addRouteShapeToMap(route){
  var strip = new H.geo.Strip(),
    routeShape = route.shape,
    polyline;

  routeShape.forEach(function(point) {
    var parts = point.split(',');
    strip.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);
  });

  polyline = new H.map.Polyline(strip, {
    style: {
      lineWidth: 4,
      strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.7)'
    }
  });
  // Add the polyline to the map
  map.addObject(polyline);
  // And zoom to its bounding rectangle
  map.setViewBounds(polyline.getBounds(), true);
}
```

The important bit is the line `map.setViewBounds()` - method, passing in the `polyline.getBounds()`. If you have more than one `polyline` - add them to an `H.map.Group` object and use the [getBounds() method](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-group.html#h-map-group__getbounds) of the group instead.

Comment: this is very helpful!